# How to recover refs/original/refs/heads/tmp?

Tags: git, recovery

Git filter-tree helpfully stored a backup in `.git/refs/original/refs/heads/tmp`. But I can't find any instructions on how to restore from it. I haven't touched the repository since then - I just changed my mind about the wisdom of that particular manipulation.

I'm guessing the answer is either a file copy or `git update-ref`, but these are pretty destructive operations, and I don't want to get it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the thing to know, from which all else flows: except when doing `git gc` (well, and things `git gc` does as well), git *never removes anything*, it only ever *adds new things*.

Let's say you have a branch that looks something like this:

```
* 9d2e82c handle another temporary failure mode
| * 2afb8a0 (resubmit) checkpoint: resubmit
| * 90dcfbb move definitinon of GRONK to sysdefs
|/  
* 1ba7847 treat XML login errors as temporary failures
```

(this is snipped and slightly modified output from `git lola`: http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html).  Now say I did something to my "resubmit" branch, like an incorrect `filter-branch`, so that I have two new commits on that branch (1234567 and 7654321, or whatever).  I realize, oh no, I did something completely broken, and I want "resubmit" to go back to pointing to commit 2afb8a0, which is the original tip of that branch.

That commit is *still in git*, and will be for several months at least (longer because you have the user-visible branch-name `original/refs/heads/tmp`—try doing `git log` on it for instance, you'll see it's there).  Find the commit ID—easy in your case, it's named `original/refs/heads/tmp`—and make your branch point there.  If you didn't have a name, you could do `git branch -d resubmit` and then `git branch resubmit 2afb8a0` (for my own example above), but you do, so:

```
git branch -D tmp
git branch -m original/refs/heads/tmp tmp
```

will delete your current `tmp` and rename the renamed one back to `tmp`.

(The new commits `filter-branch` recently added, that you decided you don't like after all, will still be in your repository.  Once you've deleted the user-visible-names they'll expire in about 3 months, after which `git gc` will remove them.)

Comment: Oh - the backup is just a ref like any other. That's the bit I was missing. :)

Comment: Aha, yes, that's a good way to put it.  But even if you lose the ref names the commits are still in there, they just become harder to find.